# Settings lost for libbylinux on ubuntu update

Tags: 20.04, updates, settings

Whenever Ubuntu 20.04 does an update that requires a reboot, I lose the settings for the [libbylinux app installed as Snap](https://snapcraft.io/libbylinux). Specifically, my library and library card number are forgotten and my place in the book I'm reading is forgotten.

It does not appear to be a permissions problem.

Output of ls snap/ -l:

total 28

drwxr-xr-x 2 bob bob 4096 Jan 14  2021 brave

drwxr-xr-x 5 bob bob 4096 May 14 10:29 gimp

drwxr-xr-x 4 bob bob 4096 Jan  5  2021 libbylinux

drwxr-xr-x 2 bob bob 4096 Jan  6  2021 notepadqq

drwxr-xr-x 5 bob bob 4096 Jul 11 10:56 snap-store

drwxr-xr-x 2 bob bob 4096 Jan  4  2021 sweethome3d-homedesign

drwxr-xr-x 5 bob bob 4096 Aug 19 08:12 thunderbird

Comment: What is libbylinux, how it was installed?

Comment: @N0rbert - Libby is a free app where you can borrow ebooks, digital audiobooks, and magazines from your public library. The linux version is installed from: https://snapcraft.io/libbylinux

Comment: On Ubuntu level it may be permissions issue. Please add the output of `ls snap/ -l` to the question. On Snap level - you have to contact Libby Snap developer to ask about implementation of session management in the app.